# Does this exemplify bad writing?

Tags: writing

As a non-native English speaker, I have trouble determining whether some ways of phrasing or using English expressions in writing are 'natural' or not. The other day I came across an article written by my old teacher, and after finishing it I felt totally confused. It reads as follows:

> It is not certain that everything has its two sides, but it is true for us to have separate minds when we talk about our home: whether it is a warm haven to stay or a dull capsule just to dwell in and escape from.
>
> Some say that nowhere is better than home, as  it keeps us from everything that is outside, no matter how fascinating or depressing it might be. Once back home, we may have for ourselves a safe distance from what we have seen and done; suddenly, the hustling of the train or the babbling of numerous strangers on the streets no longer grate on our mind as much as before. And along with it also comes the calm and silent moment to look back on, for example, the recent quarrel with one of your colleagues which you now recognize as silly and regretful, yet with a reconciled mind. No matter the events of the day, home is the place where we can have our own reflection on them all. At home there is also the mealtime where we can enjoy the feeling of sharing and getting mutually understood.
>
> Widely recognised as they are, all the thoughts above can be contrasted by a simple truth: for many times being in a bustling crowd we can still have some quiet contemplations, and clearly there are also times when we can find pure refreshment in places that are new or full of strangers. Curiously there are energies and excitedness that almost never occur to us at home but in a seaside cafe or a gallery at a less visited museum, where we simply find new energies from new things being seen and strange people being met. And the most unexpected collections to us may also lie in the houses of our acquaintances not our own, especially in choices of order and decoration, as after all, they are in some aspects 'outsiders' to us. The place where each person lives, fascinatingly, can become an establishment for his or her identity to be shown, even though it has been at times considered boring by its dwellers.
>
> So whether at home or outside, it is the benefit of having our mind strengthened from life's elements of freshness that we are always seeking and forever appreciating.

**Is it an example of unnatural or stiff writing typically produced by a non-native English speaker?** I am learning how to write too, so it would be very great if anybody can help.

Comment: It might be considered a little verbose, but it's completely literate and grammatical. It's the same kind of writing style you'd find in refined literature. Without knowing anything one way or the other, it sounds like somebody who speaks English fluently, if not natively, and who has been well educated. But if you are learning how to write, I would not start by trying to emulate this—not because it's poor, but because you should understand why it's good. (And barring some specific concern, this question seems more appropriate for a site like [Writing.SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/).)

Comment: I'm going to disagree with Jason on the first part of his comment (this person's writing style is awful) -- but he had a great conclusion.  At any rate, try to obliterate this instructor and their writing style from your mind.  There's no shortage of positive models of good writing and proper use of the English language.

Comment: I agree with @aprarente001.  The writing is awful and it is obviously written by someone whose first language isn't English.  The writer makes very basic conjugation errors and frequently uses unnatural phrasings.  What makes it somewhat difficult to understand, aside from what I've already mentioned, is it appears the writer used a thesaurus to go through it and switch out simple words for bigger ones he or she thought would make him or her seem smarter while unwittingly using those bigger words incorrectly at times.

Comment: Yes, it exemplifies bad writing.

Comment: @Nancy I take it that you think James Joyce was a terrible writer? ;)